# multi dimensional array from a joined mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

So this has been kicking my butt a bit. A little explanation is that I have 2 tables - equipment and ehours. Essentially, the equipment remains static and is transferred to a project and then is tracked on a daily basis on it's usage. `equipment.eid` is the unique identifier for the equipment and is then used in each ehours entry.

Following is the query I am using to create my ouput. The output I'm getting is sorted correctly, but can't figure out how to output properly.

```
SELECT e.cid, e.eid, h.pid, h.hdate, e.eqid, e.name, e.make, e.model, h.hours, e.uid
FROM equipment e
LEFT JOIN ehours h on h.eid = e.eid
AND MONTH(h.hdate) = $data[month] AND YEAR(h.hdate) = $data[year]
ORDER BY cid ASC, eid ASC, pid ASC, hdate ASC
```

The problem I'm having is that in a given month a piece of equipment may be on 2 separate projects. The query shows the following...

```
cid | eid | pid  | hdate      | eqid | name     | make        | model | hours | uid
4   | 55  | 1    | 2012-11-01 | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 |       | 5     | 1
4   | 55  | 1    | 2012-11-07 | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 |       | 5     | 1
4   | 55  | 1    | 2012-11-10 | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 |       | 2     | 1
4   | 55  | 1    | 2012-11-13 | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 |       | 3     | 1
4   | 55  | 4    | 2012-11-13 | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 |       | 2     | 1
```

The output needs to have a 2nd dimension of the dates which will be output in the proper days for the month. The final display will show all dates of the month. For instance, the first `eid` will output on one line with the `pid` of 1 and have the `hours` in the proper day of the month. It will then have a line afterwards with the same piece of equipment but having a `pid` of 4.

So, anyway I'm needing to somehow create the dates into a 2nd dimension of the array that I can walk through as I output each row. Or maybe a 3rd dimension to catch the hours that are associated with each date? I've looked at several php methods to attempt this, but have been unsuccessful so far. Any help is greatly appreciated. Wow - this turned into a novel.

**Edited:**

The following is what output should be...

```
pid | eqid | name     | make        | 11-01 | 11-02 | ... | 11-07 | ... | 11-10 | ... | 11-13
1   | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 | 5     | 0     | ... | 5     | ... | 2     | ... | 3
4   | E8   | Forklift | Clark CGP25 | 0     | 0     | ... | 0     | ... | 0     | ... | 2
```

Would also have to account for a NULL value for `pid`

Comment: so what you want to output is exactly what you recieve you just want to have a line between 2012-11-13 pid 1 and 2012-11-13 pid 4?

Comment: Yes - for one. I'm thinking of a spreadsheet. First line would have the project, then equipment information, then all the days of the month and year that is selected, then in each day of the month would be the proper hours. The next line would have the same equipment but the next pid and again with the proper hours noted on the correct dates. If there was only one date for each piece of equipment it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i understand what you are after, what you can do is create an associative array for each PID containing the date lines for each one something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  $output[$row['pid']][] = $row;
}
```

then you need to go over the new array

```
foreach ($output as $job)
{
  foreach ($job as $line)
  {
    // do some formatiign here
    print_r($line)
  }
  echo "<hr>"; // this is the line or whatever seperator you need
}
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I added some additional information above to show what output should look like. I'll see if I can get what you stated to work today. Thanks.